# Cutom loop function looping infinitely

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, higher-order-functions

I'm new to JavaScript
I need to make a function that works like this:

```
loop(3, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log);
// → 3
// → 2
// → 1
```

Here is my code:

```
function loop(counter, condition, update, fun){
    while(condition(counter)){
        fun(counter);
        update(counter);
    }
}
```

The while loop is running infinitely, and nothing is logging on console.

---

Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to update `counter` *locally*. Right now you throw away the return value of the `update` function.

Comment: The `update` function isn't "updating" anything. It just *returns a new value*, but that value isn't saved anywhere.

Comment: Consider not using `while`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Nothing wrong with `while`, and since the condition fn is arbitrary I don't see a huge reason to use anything else. What would you suggest instead of `while`?

Comment: @DaveNewton probably recursion

Comment: You need something like `counter = update(counter);`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Recursion?! Why? There's nothing intrinsically recursive about this at all.

Comment: @DaveNewton Why not? The condition to stop is already there, most of the internals would be applying the functions given. See [Nina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63000558/989920).

Comment: @evolutionxbox Why not? Because it's inefficient on non-TCO JS implementations (like V8 which AFAIK doesn't do TCO) and there's no benefit because it's not a naturally-recursive problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks buddy, such a silly mistake I was doing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update approach.

```js
function loop(counter, check, update, fn) {
    while (check(counter)) {
        fn(counter);
        counter = update(counter);
    }
}

loop(3, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log);
```

An recursive approach.

```js
function loop(counter, check, update, fn) {
    if (!check(counter)) return;
    fn(counter);
    loop(update(counter), check, update, fn);
}

loop(3, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log);
```

Comment: Why? This doesn't appear to be a problem best solved through recursion.